# 2checkout long lived token or start 1 year recurring billing after 1 month

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, recurring-billing, 2checkout

I'm integrating [2checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/) in my site and I have a problem with my subscription policy. I want my all user will signup with their credit card but they will charge after 1 month, after 1 month free use they will be charged to a subscription of every 1 year with recurring billing. Is there any way to start a recurring billing after 1 month?

Or can I generate a long lived token which will not expire in 1 month?

NB: I don't want to store credit card information to my server and I want user to put their credit card information only when they signup and not again but when they want to restart recurring billing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the startup fee to a negative amount to effectively give them the first month free?

> startupFee : Any start up fees for the product or service. Can be negative to provide discounted first installment pricing, but cannot equal or surpass the product price. (Optional)

[Create Sale](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/create-sale)

A side note: the token is actually only good for 30 minutes and not 1 month as far as I can tell.

Comment: my subscription plan is yearly basis, so if I give startup fee negative of one month than user have to pay 11 months subscription payment first. But if you read my question carefully I don't want to do that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. As far as I can tell, the API does not support token storage outside of 30 minutes so you would need to either run the first 12 months as 11 months or re/accept the credit card after the first month (grace period).